# Convert UNIX/epoch time to h:mm

Tags: java, android

**What I need**:

I need to convert something like this "1500322822.816785" to a format like this "3:45 PM".

**What I've tried**:

```
    public static String fromUnixTimestamp(String timestamp) {

    double itemDouble = Double.parseDouble(timestamp);
    long itemLong = (long) itemDouble;
    Date itemDate = new Date(itemLong);
    String itemDateStr = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(itemDate);


    return itemDateStr;
}
```

**What happens**:

When the double is converted a long it gets rounded (I think), so all items have the same time if they're within a few minutes of each other.

Comment: Which precision you need? seconds is enough? If yes you can simply remove the decimal part and convert only 1500322822 part to get a date with seconds

Comment: I'd like to be a precise as possible but I think removing the decimals would be fine. I'm reading the values from a JSON file so I think I'd have to round them after reading them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with this:

```
//i've removed the decimal digits from your number and added the L for long casting
Date itemDate = new Date(1500322822L * 1000);
//or alternatively you can do 
//Date itemDate = new Date((long)1500322822 * 1000);
String text = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(itemDate);
//text is now "17-07-2017 08:20:22 PM"
```

You need to multiply UNIX time x 1000 because Java `java.util.Date` class expects milliseconds

Comment: Multiplying by 1000 fixed it. Thanks